# axios call data return useState undefined

Tags: reactjs, axios

I want to get data from API server.

```
const [datas, setDatas]=useState({
        datas: []
});
```

```
useEffect(()=> {
        apiClient.post(url) // apiClient is axios.create function
        .then((response)=>
            setData(datas: response.data.response))
},[])
```

but `console.log(data)` return `undefined`. However, if fix a part of the code or do something else, it gets the right value.

So I deleted the deps of useEffect. Then I fell into the API call loop. One of the solutions I found was to put the initial value of useState into an empty array.However, the value was returned as undefined even if you put it in an empty array. 
There is no problem calling the server. `console.log(response)` returns a valid response value. 
I'd appreciate it if you could tell me the solution.

Comment: whats your response looks like ?


Does it have a key named "response" ?

Comment: Sorry The call error was corrected. Data type is json

Comment: Key named is “response”

Comment: your code is syntactically invalid and will not run

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
useEffect(()=> {
        apiClient.post(url) // apiClient is axios.create function
        .then((response)=>
            setStations({datas: response.data.response})
},[])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use setDatas as you named it:

```
    useEffect(()=> {
        apiClient.post(url) // apiClient is axios.create function
        .then((response)=>
            setDatas({datas: response.data.response)})
},[])
```

Answer (score 0):

your usage of `useState` is not entirely correct.
if you just want an array, use `const [datas, setDatas] = useState([])`. no need for the additional inheritance. which results in:

```
useEffect(()=> {
        apiClient.post(url) // apiClient is axios.create function
        .then((response)=>
            setData(response.data.response)
},[])
```

assuming `response.data.response` is the desired array.

if you insist on the inheritance (`useState({datas: []})`, then you need to wrap it when setting as well: `...setData({datas: response.data.response})`.